# mysql select distinct and discard others

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table and i want to mark all first item as OK and all other item as rejected in mysql table and change their status to Not Ok

can we do this one query for each product using PHP ??

here is table structure

```
id      prod_id   position  status 

3056620 4610395144282   20  0
3056619 4610395144282   7   0
3020612 4610395144282   19  0
3020611 4610395144282   7   0
3020610 4610395144282   6   0
2996086 4610395144282   17  0
2996085 4610395144282   6   0
2996055 4610395144282   17  0
2996054 4610395144282   6   0
2994301 4610395144282   29  0
2994300 4610395144282   16  0
2994299 4610395144282   6   0
2994279 4610395144282   26  0
2994278 4610395144282   19  0
2994277 4610395144282   15  0
2994276 4610395144282   11  0
2994275 4610395144282   6   0
2989321 4610395144282   24  0
2989320 4610395144282   22  0
2989319 4610395144282   19  0
2989318 4610395144282   17  0
2989317 4610395144282   13  0
2989316 4610395144282   10  0
2989315 4610395144282   8   0
2989314 4610395144282   6   0
```

i want to mark all such column where **prod_id**  position is repeating as 1

for example we can see that  Prod_id  4610395144282    position 7 is appearing 2 times, so i will ignore first appearnce and mark all other appeparance as 1 in status. 
next is position 6 appears several times. i will ignore first appearnce or last appearance and mark all other as status=1 with same position for same product.

first and last are filtered by id . order by id desc limit 1
any help will be great. i can get unique row by  using distinct but how to mark others as status 1. we use php and hope to figure out some fast way

Comment: you question a some flaws what is first and what is last, how are the rows sorted

Comment: by id.......................

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.47 ..................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL version 8.0 or higher, You may achieve this using window functions -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE S
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY position ORDER BY id) RN
            FROM YOUR_TABLE)
      WHERE RN = 1) T ON S.id = T.id
                     AND S.prod_id = T.prod_id
                     AND S.position = T.position
SET S.status = 1;
```

If you are using lower versions, You may generate row_number with sub-query as -

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE S
JOIN (SELECT id, prod_id, position
      FROM (SELECT id, prod_id, @row_number:=CASE WHEN @position=position
                                                       THEN @row_number + 1
                                                  ELSE 1
                                             END AS rn, @position:=position position
            FROM YOUR_TABLE
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number :=0, @position := 1) vars
            GROUP BY position
            HAVING COUNT(position) > 1
            ORDER BY position) X
      WHERE RN = 1) T ON S.id = T.id
                     AND S.prod_id = T.prod_id
                     AND S.position = T.position
SET S.status = 1;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=b4f879d23715976e5d6605cfc0d3f567)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211031/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-bajpai-mysql-select-distinct-and-discard-others).